# cc: error: unknown argument: '-fformat-extensions'

Tags: gcc, github, freebsd

I am posting a question because of the problem:

> cc: error: unknown argument: '-fformat-extensions'

The following error occurred while compiling FreeBSD src with gcc.

Below is a log.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
>>> stage 3.1: making dependencies
--------------------------------------------------------------
cc: error: unknown argument: '-fformat-extensions'
--- vmx_genassym.o ---
*** [vmx_genassym.o] Error code 1

make[4]: stopped in /usr/KRSense/tmp/FreeBSD-src/sys/modules/vmm
1 error

make[4]: stopped in /usr/KRSense/tmp/FreeBSD-src/sys/modules/vmm
--- depend_subdir_vmm ---
*** [depend_subdir_vmm] Error code 2
```

Comment: Please add the output of `cc --version` to your post (not in comments).

Answer (score 1):

The FreeBSD system compiler has customer patches which adds the (curiously named) `-fformat-extensions` option:

- [Why can't lang/gcc4X compilers build kernel modules?](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-ports/2013-May/083387.html)

You will have to use the system compiler or another compiler which has been patched in the same way.